# Two options, and a third, which renders the first two redundant

Tags: checkboxes, options

I am in a predicament, so I would appreciate any help that you experts can provide.

I have two options, A and B, which say either is required and a third option, C which says either A or B is needed.

Now if i give these options to the user, I am afraid the user may select C, and A, or B. which is a strange selection because this way they are saying, I want B, and I want A, or B.

I don't know if i am making sense, so, I have here, and images with an example.

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: Is the selection [pb] [pb or j] not redundant? Will they then receive 2 sandwiches? What if they want 2 j?

Answer (score 2):

***Radio buttons*** are my first choice when presenting mutually exclusive options to a user.

You could also rename the PB or J option to "don't mind".

Comment: Thanks PixelSnader, and Franchesca, for your replies. I found out that choosing PB or J, should disable the other two.